# Green's Theorem for an off-centered circle

Tags: line-integrals, greens-theorem

I have the following problem where I'm trying to figure out how to convert a circle whose equation is $(x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 = 25 $ traversed counterclockwise.

Here's the integral

$$ \oint_C 2ydx + 5xdy $$

From what I can see,

$$ x = 1 + 5cos\theta$$  $$ y = -3 + 5sin\theta$$

$$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$
where Green's theorem would yield $3$ when taking the partial derivates.

I know for a fact that my outer integral ranges from $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ but I cannot figure out how my $r$ ranges in this case. Does it have an affect or should my limits simply be:

$$ 3\int_o^{2\pi} \int_o^5 rdrd\theta$$

which doesn't seem right; I feel like it should be somewhere in the lines of

$$ 3\int_o^{2\pi} \int_{1 + 5cos\theta}^{??} rdrd\theta$$

Comment: why not just do it in rectanglar coordinates?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is the original integral?  You have a double integral with integrand $2ydx+5xdy$.  Do you find that inconsistent?

Comment: @Dr.MV see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem) we have

$$\oint_C(Pdx+Qdy)=\iint_S\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy$$

With $P=2y$, $Q=5x$, and $C$ is the boundary of $S$, a circular disk region with radius $5$ and center $(1,3)$, we have

$$\oint_C(2ydy+5xdx)=\iint_S 3 dxdy=3 (5)^2=75\pi$$

---

Direct Evaluation;

Let $x=1+5\cos t$ and $y=3+5\sin t$.  Then, $dx=-5\sin tdt$ and $dy=5\cos tdt$.   Thus,

$$\oint_C(2ydy+5xdx)=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(2(3+5\sin t)(-5\sin t)+5(1+5\cos t)(5\cos t)\right)dt=75\pi$$

Comment: I was able to derive the same answer by direct evaluation. However, the problem I was facing was to convert the same problem into polar coordinates, which should of course yield the same answer. It seems that the off-center property had no effect on the range of $r$  given $$ 3\int_o^{2\pi} \int_o^5 rdrd\theta$$ which also yields $75\pi$. Is this always the case?

Comment: @Dimitri First translate coordinates to a new Cartesian system $(x',y')$ where $x=x'-1$ and $y=y'-3$.  Then in the new "primed coordinate system, convert to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.   You need not evaluate in a polar coordinate system of the original Cartesian coordinates.  Make sense?

Comment: You're most welcome!  It was my pleasure.